# Weird issue while loading properties files from class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created this test app to explain the issue I am having.

I have two properties files with same keys and total three properties files in class path.

1.mysql.properties

2.vertica.properties

3.other.properties

I am getting following error while running the app.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mysql-username' in value "${mysql-username}"
```

Here is the code.

```
package com.test.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApplication.class);
        MyController bean = applicationContext.getBean(MyController.class);
        bean.log();
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer otherProps() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

        final List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

        resourceList.add(getOtherResourceFile());

        ppc.setLocations(resourceList.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer verticaProps() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        ppc.setPlaceholderPrefix("${vertica-");

        final List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

        resourceList.add(getVerticaResourceFile());

        ppc.setLocations(resourceList.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer mysqlProps() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        ppc.setPlaceholderPrefix("${mysql-");
        final List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

        resourceList.add(getDatabasePropertiesFile());

        ppc.setLocations(resourceList.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

        return ppc;
    }

    private Resource getOtherResourceFile() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("other.properties");
        return resource;
    }

    private Resource getVerticaResourceFile() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("vertica.properties");
        return resource;
    }

    private Resource getDatabasePropertiesFile() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("mysql.properties");
        return resource;
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
/*
 * MyController.java
 */
package com.test.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
@Component
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MySqlProperties mySqlProperties;
    @Autowired
    private VerticaProperties verticaProperties;
    @Autowired
    private OtherProperties otherProperties;

    public String log() {
        System.out.println(mySqlProperties.getUsername());
        System.out.println(verticaProperties.getUsername());
        System.out.println(otherProperties.getKey());
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

MySqlProperties.java

```
/*
 * MySqlProperties.java
 */
package com.test.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
@Component
public class MySqlProperties {

    @Value("${mysql-username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${mysql-password}")
    private String password;

    //getter
}
```

VerticaProperties.java

```
/*
 * VerticaProperties.java
 */
package com.test.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
@Component
public class VerticaProperties {

    @Value("${vertica-username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${vertica-password}")
    private String password;

    //getter
}
```

OtherProperties.java

```
/*
 * OtherProperties.java
 */
package com.test.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
@Component
public class OtherProperties {

    @Value("${key}")
    private String key;
    @Value("${key1}")
    private String key1;

    //getter
}
```

These are the properties files.

mysql.properties

```
username=mysql
password=mysql
```

vertica.properties

```
username=vertica
password=vertica
```

other.properties

```
key=value
key1=value1
```

**Weird Issue:** When I remove the following code from DemoApplication.java the app works expected.

```
@Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer otherProps() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

        final List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

        resourceList.add(getOtherResourceFile());

        ppc.setLocations(resourceList.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

        return ppc;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the reason is the conflict between two placeholders? OtherPlaceHolder accepts any property name, MySqlPlaceHolder accepts mysql-* properties. Anyway, I think you can try to use `@PropertySource("classpath:something.properties")`. It looks much simplier:)

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov That does not work as key is same for two properties files. So username,password will override.

Comment: I think you have to set `setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` on the `ppc`s so that all `ppc`s get the chance to resolve placeholders.